# How to hook one custom post-types post to another?

Tags: custom-post-types

Basically I have got two custom post-types "news" and "authors". So I want to display both of them separately, however I want to hook them dynamically. So when you create a post aka. news.. then you could select the author from a list.
Later on that author will be displayed under the post as "About The Author" and would link to the authors detailed view.

I'm sorry, I don't have any code to start with as wordpress is unknown territory for me and I couldn't find any keywords to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Use Posts 2 Posts plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/